# Return parameter failing in Serverless Azure Function in Python

Tags: python, azure, serverless-framework

I have created a project using azure-python serverless framework template. 
When I try to run locally: serverless offline, I get following error:

> cannot load the goodbye function: the following parameters are declared in function.json but not in Python: {'res'}

If I modify manually function.json and replace name value "res" of parameter with $return, everything works. However, this file is regenerated by framework. How to define this parameter as $return in function.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your configuration file. If you specify the configuration file, you can modify the `name` from "res" to "$return" in it. If you didn't specify the configuration file, the configuration file should be `serverless.yml|.yaml|.js|.json`. Please refer to the screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

Here provide two links([screenshot1](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/cli-reference/deploy/), [screenshot2](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/function-apps/)) for the screenshots above(but I can't find `serverless.yml` for python sample, the second screenshot is for nodejs), you can also find more information about serverless in these two links.

Hope it helps~